# 'Drools Camel Server' vs 'KIE-WB Execution Server'

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie

What is the difference between **"Drools Camel Server"** and **"KIE-WB Execution Server"** ?
Do they serve the same purpose of executing rules/processes in remote server ?

[KIE-WB document:](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0.1/userguide/jBPMRemoteAPI.html#remote.rest.execute)

> The workbench contains an execution server (for executing processes
>   and tasks), which also allows you to invoke various process and task
>   related operations through a remote API. As a result, you can setup
>   your process engine "as a service" and integrate this into your
>   applications easily by doing remote requests and/or sending the
>   necessary triggers to the execution server whenever necessary (without
>   the need to embed or manage this as part of your application).

[Drools Camel Server document:](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html/ch.server.html)

> The drools camel server (drools-camel-server) module is a war which
>   you can deploy to execute KnowledgeBases remotely for any sort of
>   client application. This is not limited to JVM application clients,
>   but any technology that can use HTTP, through a REST interface. This
>   version of the execution server supports stateless and stateful
>   sessions in a native way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some way they serve to the same purpose. The KIE Workbench Remote server that was bundled with 6.0 and 6.1 was targeted mainly to process executions. We made sure that it covers most of what is needed when you are running business processes. For rules there is a different multi purpose execution server that is being developed and it is targeted to 6.2+. If you are looking for a purely Rules execution server you can take a look at the drools camel server or get in contact and try the latest snapshots of the new work that is being done.

HTH

Comment: Thank you @salaboy. Yes, I need a solution to purely execute the Rules remotely and expose execution-engine as a service.Let me know the latest multi-purpose execution server snapshots to try.

Comment: If upgrading from a system that used the Drools 5 Camel Server but depended on triggering a "process" (equivalent to what at the time was called a Rule Flow, .rf file) to control order of rule execution, which server would be the best to migrate to?

Comment: You should try the KIE Worbench and the new Drools Execution server provided in 6.1 If you only want in memory processes then the Drools Execution Server provides what you are looking for.

Comment: Is the Drools Camel Server something that is being sunsetted?

Comment: Sorry, I am getting confused, isn't the Drools Execution Server something being released in 6.2?  Thanks for your help navigating this.

Comment: Yeah, I think that Drools camel server is dead now. Here is the code for the new kie-server -> https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/tree/master/kie-server