# .NET application remotely invoke drools workbench 6.1 to execute rule

Tags: drools, workbench

Is it possible that the drools workbench provide REST/SOAP API for .NET/python applications to execute rules.

thanks,
Kalin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a REST API, but it would be of no use to you. The rules don't get executed in Workbench. It's really just a repository for them. The REST API would let you download the rules, but you wouldn't be able to execute them in a .NET application.

Instead you would need to run up a rules service of your own. You could create a minimal Java web application, with REST/SOAP operations.

However, there is also the Drools Camel Server, which can be configured to load rules from your Workbench and expose them through a REST API. See the docs here:

http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#ch.server

Comment: In response to the reply you posted as a question, you might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615823/drools-camel-server-vs-kie-wb-execution-server