# Drools Camel Server

Tags: apache-camel, drools, drools-guvnor, drools-planner

Currently we are in **Drools Camel Server 5.5.0**; we would like to upgrade to new version. When I check the Drools download page which shows **6.4** is the latest, and does not have the **Drools Camel server** build. I find description provided for **KIE Execution Server**, which resemblance with the **drools Camel Server** feature. Is Drools server renamed as **KIE Execution Server**?

Answer (score 0):

See this post ['Drools Camel Server' vs 'KIE-WB Execution Server'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615823/drools-camel-server-vs-kie-wb-execution-server)  which describes how Drools v5.5 Drools-Camel-Server capabilities are now integrated into KIE-Workbench Remote.